# Debug hover in VSCode is not showing variable values in Python

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code

In a Django view context, I am trying to see the variable values at debug time in the hover, and they are not showing up.

Version: 1.53.2 (user setup)
Commit: 622cb03f7e070a9670c94bae1a45d78d7181fbd4
Date: 2021-02-11T11:48:04.245Z
Electron: 11.2.1
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

What I expect to see:

[image: Debug Hover]

What I actually see:

[image: minimal hover]

Python Extension v2021.1.502429796

Language Server: Pylance

Comment: Did you use any settings in "settings.json" and "launch.json"? Have you tried reloading VS Code and waiting for its language service to load?

Comment: Yeah I tried changing a few to no avail, and restarting between each change.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the python extension and the Pylance extension? It is recommended that you disable other VS Code extensions that you do not use to avoid their impact on this feature.

Comment: no other extensions and reinstalled to no avail.

Comment: -Have you tried testing other codes? Is the variable value also not displayed during debugging?

Comment: Other languages?  no.  And yes, the issue is during debugging.  hence "at debug time".

Comment: -I mean other python code, does the same thing happen?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be the whole language server?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint during debugging? And is the variable value displayed in the debug bar on the left side of VS Code? In addition, please provide us with a minimal example that can reproduce this problem so that we can help you better.